# Media Query - Screen height / device

Tags: css

I have built a site that contains an expanding / contracting search form with fixed position.  This works great on a desktop - but of course would be problematic on any advice that doesn't allow for the required height.  I was going to use a media query for height ie -

```
@media (min-height: 700px) {
    #quick-search{position:relative;}

}
```

and place the quick search inline on a device without scrollable height - to ensure it can be scrolled.

But my understanding is that some device OS / browsers refer to height as document height rather than viewport height - so the above solution wouldn't convert the QS to inline for all required scenarios.  Am i correct with this?  If so can anyone suggest an alternative solution that should fit all scenarios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you have the correct meta tag it will calcuate using the viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

To use the screen height add `screen` to the media

```
@media screen and (min-height: 700px) {
    #quick-search{position:relative;}

}
```

A more detailed explanation here: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html

Comment: cool - this only mentions height though - as does the meta tag - would this be relevant for height also?

Comment: Yup this is relevant for height too. the width=device-width also scales the height.